# Cannot find macro `log` in this scope when using log with Rocket

Tags: rust, rust-rocket

I am getting a compiler error trying to use the log crate in a package in a workspace. The other crates in the workspace are using logging without problem.

Cargo.toml:

```
[dependencies]
log = "^0"
rocket = "^0"

[dependencies.uuid]
version = "^0"
features = ["v4"]
```

lib.rs:

```rust
#![feature(proc_macro_hygiene, decl_macro)]

use rocket::{
    Request, 
    Data, 
    Response
};

use rocket::request::{
    self, 
    FromRequest,
    Outcome
};

use rocket::fairing::{
    Fairing, 
    Info, 
    Kind
};

use uuid::Uuid;

use std::fmt;

use log;



pub struct LoggerFairing {
    service_name: &'static str
}


impl LoggerFairing {
    pub fn new(service_name: &'static str) -> Self {
        LoggerFairing {
            service_name
        }
    }
}


impl Fairing for LoggerFairing {
    fn info(&self) -> Info {
        Info {
            name: self.service_name,
            kind: Kind::Request | Kind::Response
        }
    }


    fn on_request(&self, req: &mut Request, _: &Data) {
        let ip_addr = req.client_ip().map(|addr| addr.to_string())
            .unwrap_or("IP Address unknown".to_string());

        let method = req.method();

        let url = req.uri();

        let request_id = get_request_id(req);

        log::info!("request {:?} from {}: {} {}", request_id, ip_addr, method, url);
    }


    fn on_response(&self, req: &Request, res: &mut Response) {
        let request_id = get_request_id(req);

        let status = res.status();

        log::info!("request {:?} responded with {}", request_id, status);
    }
}


fn get_request_id<'t, 'r>(req: &'t Request<'r>) -> Option<RequestId<'t>> {
    match req.guard::<RequestId>() {
        Outcome::Success(request_id) => Some(request_id),
        _ => None
    }
}



pub struct RequestId<'t> {
    pub id: &'t Uuid
}    


impl<'t, 'r> FromRequest<'t, 'r> for RequestId<'t> {
    type Error = ();
    
    fn from_request(req: &'t Request<'r>) -> request::Outcome<Self, Self::Error> {
        let id = req.local_cache(|| Uuid::new_v4());
        
        request::Outcome::Success(RequestId {
            id
        })
    }
}


impl<'t> fmt::Display for RequestId<'t> {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter<'_>) -> fmt::Result {
        write!(f, "{}", self.id)
    }
}
```

The error message:

```
error: cannot find macro `log` in this scope
  --> utils\logging\src\lib.rs:62:9
   |
62 |         log::info!("request {:?} from {}: {} {}", request_id, ip_addr, method, url);
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   |
   = note: this error originates in a macro (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)

error: cannot find macro `log` in this scope
  --> utils\logging\src\lib.rs:71:9
   |
71 |         log::info!("request {:?} responded with {}", request_id, status);
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   |
   = note: this error originates in a macro (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)

error: aborting due to 2 previous errors

error: could not compile `logging`.
```

I've used several variations of the `use log` statement and how I'm calling the `info!` macro, but they all cause the same error message. I've tried specifying exact versions in Cargo.toml.

I'm stumped. This is exactly how I'm using log in other crates.

Comment: `log = "^0"` this is about the least useful way of specifying dependency versions.

Comment: At the very least, you need to tell us what versions you are using. Please [edit] your question to include the exact versions, ideally by reflecting that in the Cargo.toml.

Comment: This code does not produce the errors you are asking about. This only states *`std::option::Option<&uuid::Uuid>` cannot be formatted with the default formatter*.

Comment: If you are using Rocket, that also means you are using nightly Rust. You need to specify exactly which version of Rust.

Comment: *`RequestId<'_>` doesn't implement `std::fmt::Debug`*. **Please** ensure that the code you are posting produces the error you are experiencing.

Comment: It would make it easier for us to help you if you try to reproduce your error on the [Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org) if possible, otherwise in a **brand new Cargo project**, then [edit] your question to include the additional info. If it doesn't reproduce there, you will need to minimize your workspace to the basics. There are [Rust-specific MRE tips](//stackoverflow.com/tags/rust/info) you can use to reduce your original code for posting here. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Specifying the exact version of the log crate (0.4.11) in Cargo.toml fixes this problem.

I'm assuming there is something funny happening when Cargo tries to resolve the dependencies.